Unable to strip whitespace from a string using pyparsing set_parse_action()
I've got a generic "text block" element, for which I copied the whitespace-stripping code from the documentation:
import pyparsing as pp

text_block = pp.Group(
    pp.OneOrMore(
        pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd()) + pp.LineEnd().suppress(),
        stopOn=pp.StringEnd() | (pp.LineStart() + (pp.Literal("E)") | pp.Literal("F)")))
    )
).set_parse_action(pp.token_map(str.strip))

Unfortunately this returns an error:

FAIL-EXCEPTION: TypeError: descriptor 'strip' for 'str' objects
doesn't apply to a 'ParseResults' object

I replaced the use of token_map with a function:
def _strip_whitespace(tokens):
    return [token.str.strip() for token in tokens]

text_block = pp.Group(
    pp.OneOrMore(
        pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd()) + pp.LineEnd().suppress(),
        stopOn=pp.StringEnd() | (pp.LineStart() + (pp.Literal("E)") | pp.Literal("F)")))
    )
).set_parse_action(_strip_whitespace)

...but now it deletes all the text(!)

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe first check print( token ) and print( type(token) ). You could also check if it doesn't need list of striped chars - token.str.strip(" "), OR maybe this strip works in-place and it doesn't return new value but it replace existing value (end it may return empty string or None).

it would be simpler if you would create minimal reproducible example with example data in code - so we could simply copy and test.

Thank you for your replies @furas! I posted this late at night after struggling to figure it out and wasn't in the frame of mind to write a minimal example. I realised that pp.Group() was nesting my results inside another list, which is why I was dealing with a ParseResults and not a string, as I expected. Moving my whitespace-stripping code up one level to the pp.OneOrMore() resolved the issue.

Pyparsing by default automatically handles whitespace stripping in ParseResults.

The pyparsing module handles some of the problems that are typically vexing when writing text parsers:

extra or missing whitespace (the above program will also handle “Hello,World!”, “Hello , World !”, etc.)
quoted strings
embedded comments


So except in situations where you configure/instruct it to specifically capture whitespace, there's no need to strip whitespace as it will normally be auto-stripped.
SkipTo() is one of the ParserElements that can capture whitespace, because it grabs everything between the current parse location and the skipped-to character. That's why, in the table-parsing example for SkipTo, they use token_map(str.strip) in the parse action for the SkipTo.
But only the SkipTo element of the parser will require stripping, and you're trying to strip all of the tokens which is a very bad idea since, except in well-defined cases, there won't be any whitespace. So if you're going to apply str.strip in a parse action, it should be just on the SkipTo.
The AtLineStart example they give is more typical for such matching, matching each line via pp.rest_of_line (which will also grab whitespace):
test = '''\
AAA this line
AAA and this line
  AAA but not this one
B AAA and definitely not this one
'''

for t in (AtLineStart('AAA') + rest_of_line).search_string(test):
    print(t)

For your text blocks, you could just grab ALL of the lines in the block by skipping to the end marker, and then deal with the stripping and splitting when you process the results:
block_start_marker = pp.AtLineStart("(E")
text_block = (
    block_start_marker.suppress()
    + pp.SkipTo(
        pp.AtLineStart("E)") | pp.AtLineStart("F)")
    )
)

You'll get a single result with the entire block (including surrounding newlines):
>>> text_block.parse_string("\n".join([
...     "(E",
...     "    This is   ",
...     "   My text block  ",
...     "E)",
... ]))
ParseResults(['\n    This is   \n   My text block  \n'], {})

Or, you can do the line-by-line parsing thing, but you'd want to apply the parse action only to the SkipTo() elements:
block_end_marker = pp.AtLineStart("E)") | pp.AtLineStart("F)")
text_block = (
    block_start_marker.suppress()
    + pp.OneOrMore(
        pp.SkipTo("\n").set_parse_action(pp.token_map(str.strip)),
        stop_on=block_end_marker
    )
)

>>> text_block.parse_string("\n".join([
...     "(E",
...     "    This is   ",
...     "   My text block  ",
...     "E)",
... ]))
ParseResults(['This is', 'My text block'], {})


Thank you @FeRD! This is such a great answer - I'm new to Python and newer to pyparsing so these explanations are pure gold. My data is coming from an Excel spreadsheet and there are carriage return/newline combos within the data that I need to deal with.
I have found that pyparsing's handling of whitespace isn't always consistent - I have two test cases that behave differently and required me to use pp.Optional(pp.LineEnd()) which was really odd. Also, I have a case where my free-text section "E)" contains the text "F)", which is my stop marker :( I'll put together posts on these two cases

*nod* pyparsing by default will treat newlines like any other whitespace and just ignore them. You can use pp.rest_of_line.suppress() in a parser definition to explicitly parse only up until the next newline. Or, "when defining a grammar in which newlines are significant, you should call ParserElement.set_default_whitespace_chars(' \t') to remove newline from the set of skippable whitespace characters." (from the docs) Then, you'll always need to capture or suppress all newlines in the input.

For the 'case where my free-text section "E)" contains the text "F)"', that's where pp.AtLineStart() can be invaluable, as it'll ignore any matching string that isn't at the start of a line. Or, if you do have F) at the start of a line inside an (E block, presumably when the start marker is (E only E) should be recognized as the end marker, so you're better off creating two definitions — an e_text_block with e_block_start = pp.AtLineStart("(E") and e_block_end = pp.AtLineStart("E)"), and a separate f_text_block that matches the other start/end markers.

(You can always then combine those definitions with text_block = e_text_block | f_text_block, and they'll still ignore each other's end markers.)

(Where in hell did I get the idea that the text blocks here were delimited at the start by (E or (F? That's nowhere in the question, now that I reread it, and I appear to have just completely made up that parameter.)

That's OK! I think I have learned enough that I have been able to write a pretty decent parser. In the end I had to exclude newlines from the whitespace definition and handle newlines explicitly. Touch wood everything seems to work well. Thanks for your help!
